# Why after execution WCF(.svc) service throw Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, endpoint

Stuck on .net **.svc** service strange response.My service hosted in IIS and browse the service from IIS directly.
But after execution sometime like 30 minutes service throw the exception Endpoint not found, after refreshing the IIS, it's work fine again for 30 minutes. what to do?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a long-time running task, which lasts more than 30 minutes?

Comment: @Access Denied, you are right. It's a long time running task.

Comment: what event log says? Maybe there is an error in logs.